# Why selenium is unable to locate an element on bootbox modal popup?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, webdriver

I am trying to automate a webportal on windows 10 using Selenium with Python. On the process, I need to click on a 'OK' button on a bootbox modal popup. I used all the possible ways of finding the element. But its still throwing unable to find the element.

I tried finding element by ID, xpath etc.Used time waits also.

```
<div class="popup-overlay fade bootbox-confirm in" aria-hidden="false"><div class="modal-backdrop fade in" style="height: 937px;"></div><div class="popup-outer"><div class="popup-container"><div class="popup-inner modal-body"><h4 class="yellow-txt popup-title"> Framework</h4><div class="framework-txt">Are you sure want to Complete this file ?</div></div><div class="modal-footer modelcenter"><button data-bb-handler="cancel" type="button" id="okbtn" class="btn btn-yellow">Cancel</button>&nbsp;<button data-bb-handler="confirm" type="button" id="okbtn" class="btn btn-yellow">OK</button>&nbsp;</div></div></div></div>
```

my code :

```
qccomplete=driver.find_element_by_id("btnQcComplete").click()
time.sleep(2)

driver.switch_to_alert()

time.sleep(2)
qccomplete_ok=driver.find_element_by_id("okbtn").click()
```

Comment: Share your code and HTML. No point in guessing what might be happening.

Answer (score 0):

The element you are trying to click is dynamically generated. That's why you need to add a wait before trying to click on it. Try modifying the lines with the click like this (and you can lose the `Sleep`):

```
qccomplete=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "btnQcComplete")).click()

qccomplete_ok = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "okbtn")).click()
```

Where you will need to import this at the top of the script:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```